# Which way to update apex class through API is preffered: MetadataContainer in Tooling API or compileClasses in Apex API?

Tags: apex, api, java

I need to save some Apex classes through API in java and this question confused me:

In documentation for the **Tooling API** I found an example how to update Apex class using **MetadataContainer**. This example includes a lot of lines of code and about three API calls to server.

Then I found out that I can easily update an apex class using **compileClasses** or **compileAndTest** call in **Apex API**. And this way is much more comfortable for me for many reasons:

1) I need only one API call

2) There is much fewer code

3) I DON'T need to know an Id of an Apex class

4) With this call I can send many classes without knowing if they already exist or not, and everything will be done well : new classes will be created and existing classes will be updated.

So is there any reason why I should use **Tooling API** and **MetadataContaine**r for that purpose instead of using **Apex API** and **compileClasses**?

And by the way - the same question about **create** call in **Soap API**. Can I just always use **Apex API** for all this purposes?

Or there are some details which I don't know/understand or any side effects in using **Apex API** for such purposes?

I'm using developer edition. Is it possible that in production edition or in sandbox it will work other way?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go with the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/index.htm) over the [Apex API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm). The Apex API isn't really getting updates any more and has largely been replaced by the Tooling API. Long term you will have more options using the Tooling API.

That said, the Apex API should remain functional and is a valid option if you want to keep your API calls to a minimum and don't know if the classes exist or not.

If you have a new ApexClass you can do one call to the Tooling API create method. If your have one or more existing Apex classes use the MetadataContainter to update them all in one go. Yes it is 3 calls to create the MetadataContainer, then the ApexClassMembers, and then the ContainerAsyncRequest.

With the Apex API you would need to use [compileAndTest()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm) against a production environment rather than [compileClasses()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_compileclasses.htm).